# Replace string CRLF(has empty space in front) with LF C#

Tags: c#, string

I have a string like this:

```
string str="My name is John.  \r\nI am in Boston. \r\nI like the school here. "
```

Question is how can I replace these `\r\n`(CRLF) with just `\n`(LF).

Look there are empty spaces in front of \r\n in many places of the string.
Also, there can be empty space at the end or at the front.

Can I use Regex or simple Replace function?

Comment: Have you tried anything (either Regex or simple Replace)? Have you faced any problems?

Comment: Both options seem easy enough to try, so I'd suggest to try both, and come back when you encounter a specific problem

Comment: Yes you can use both Regex or simple Replace function.

Comment: I would go with a replace function, regex is an overkill to this question

Comment: Ditto @LeandroSoares - just to elaborate, you might also want to replace your `\r\n` with `Environment.NewLine` variable :)

Comment: If I'm reading your question correctly, are you more concerned about the whitespace between your text and newline?

Comment: how can I remove the space in front of the \r\n. I know I can try: str.Replace("\r\n",\"\n") but how about the space?

Comment: I've added an answer which also shows you how to remove the whitespace :)

Answer (score 2):

**To replace the newlines:**

Same as @Thomas Ayoub's answer, if you're just looking to replace the `\r\n` with `\n`:

```
string str = "My name is John.  \r\nI am in Boston. \r\nI like the school here. ";
var output = str.Replace("\r\n", "\n");
```

**To remove the whitespace:**

If you're looking to remove whitespace between the text and `\r\n` characters, also:

I would suggest splitting by new line and trimming, then joining again with a new line.

Like this:

```
string str = "My name is John.  \r\nI am in Boston. \r\nI like the school here. ";
var strParts = str.Split("\r\n").Select(x => x.Trim()); // Split and trim
var newStr = strParts.Join("\n"); // Join back up again.
```

Or a "one-liner":

```
var tidyString = str.Split("\r\n")
                    .Select(x => x.Trim())
                    .Join("\n");
```

Output should be:

> `"My name is John.\nI am in Boston.\nI like the school here."`

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: See [system.environment.newline](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline(v=vs.110).aspx) : *A string containing "\r\n" for non-Unix platforms*. You'll replace nothing...

Answer (score 1):

You can use [String.Replace()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
string str = "My name is John.  \r\nI am in Boston. \r\nI like the school here. ";
var output = str.Replace("\r\n", "\n");
```

output:

> "My name is John.  \nI am in Boston. \nI like the school here. "

---

If you want to remove leading/trailling spaces use `Trim()` function:

```
output = output.Trim();
```

output:

> "My name is John.  \nI am in Boston. \nI like the school here."

Comment: @GeoffJames You could post your answer instead of editing

Comment: How can I remove the spaces@Thomas Ayoub "My name is John. \nI am in Boston. \nI like the school here. "

Comment: @ThomasAyoub - your edit only removes the whitespace from the start and end of the entire string... - I *think* that the OP needs the whitespace from between all of the lines

Comment: Space is inside the whole string in front of \n. Trim() removes space only from front or end. I am not sure.

Comment: @AbuAlam I've already answered this issue in my answer - please see

Comment: @AbuAlam See Geoff answer, it does the work quite well :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression for this and do something like this:

```
 string str = "My name is John.  \r\nI am in Boston. \r\nI like the school here. ";
  Regex rgx = new Regex("\\s*\\r\\n");
  string result = rgx.Replace(str , "\\n");
```

Comment: Can I do the rgx and replace in 1 line? Regex rgx = new Regex("\\s*\\r\\n");
  string result = rgx.Replace(str , "\\n");

Comment: Thx. I will use the rgx one. Thanks everyone to answer back in such a  short time.